# Handle Multiple Incoming Data

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, backgroundworker

I'm creating a UI that uses rabbitmq to receive multiple lists of type 'StorageMessage'. I'm using a background worker to merge all the data from the lists into a datatable and I bind to the gridview in the UI. I have put the method that receives the messages below, my problem is that the UI doesn't display all the data I expect it to. I'm guessing its because the background work is busy when the message comes in. Whats the correct approach to deal with these types of situations?

```
    public void OnMessageArrived(MessageArrivedEventArgs<object> args)
    {
        var topicName = args.MessagingParticipant.TopicName;
        if (_logger.IsInfoEnabled)
            _logger.InfoFormat("Message Received from {0}", topicName);
        try
        {
            if (args.To == _uniqueId.ToString() || args.To.EqualsOrdinalIgnoreCase("all"))
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    var receivedMessage = Serialization.FromJsonString<StorageMessage>(args.MessageBody);
                    if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
                    {
                        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(receivedMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.Error("An error occurred whilst processing the received message.", exception);
        }
    }
```

The RunWorkComplete Code looks lie

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var res = e.Result as DataTable;
            _storageDataTable = ReorderTable(res, "Date", "Factor", "Aldbrough", "Holford", "Humbly Grove", "Stublach", "Holehouse Farm", "Hatfield Moor", "Hornsea", "Hill Top", "Rough", "South Hook", "Isle Of Grain", "Dragon");
            UpdateDataTable();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

And the updateDataTable code is:

```
    private void UpdateDataTable()
    {
        try
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => UpdateDataTable()));
            }
            else
            {
                radGridView1.SuspendLayout();
                radGridView1.GroupDescriptors.Clear();
                radGridView1.DataSource = null;
                radGridView1.DataSource = _storageDataTable;
                radGridView1.GroupDescriptors.Add("Factor", ListSortDirection.Ascending);
               // radGridView1.MasterTemplate.AutoExpandGroups = true;
                radGridView1.Refresh();
                radGridView1.ResumeLayout(true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.Error("Encountered an error while updating the data table.", exception);
        }
    }
```

Thanks 
Elias

Comment: You refresh your GridView when you have new messages processed?

Comment: @Raskayu yes i reset the datasource. I've edited my post to include more detail.